# Enter Parameter Value Dialog Box when opening form

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I have a form open and I have set the ID number up as a hyperlink to another form. I have created the code below to open up however it now comes up with the Enter Parameter Value dialog box. When I put the ID number it opens correctly.

```
Private Sub StudentID_Click()
    Dim recordID As Integer
    recordID = Me.StudentID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Students Extended", , , "Studentid=StudentNumber"
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused at what the problem is, and what you're looking for. Can you please be more specific about what you need done?

Comment: Is it possible for you to export your form and VBA code so that we can see the full context of your situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are after something like this:

```
Private Sub StudentID_Click()

    Dim recordID As Long

    recordID = Me.StudentID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Students Extended", , , "Studentid = " & recordID & ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Joseph, I'm trying to stop the enter parameter value box from appearing when I click on the hyperlink

Comment: Gustav, I've tried the code you provided but the dialog box still appears.

Comment: If it asks for StudentID, then it hasn't a field of that name. Review your recordsource of the form.